# Block not working after Magento update

Tags: blocks, upgrade, static-block, permissions, best-seller

I recently upgraded from Magento 1.5.1 to Magento 1.9.2.3 and noticed that a block on my webshop doesn't work anymore. I've got a static block called "Bestsellers" and in that block I have this peace of code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_bestseller" template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml"}}
```

This worked on my old webshop, but not a the new one. I've tried changing the type to `core/template`, I've tried adding the blocks to System -> Permissions -> Blocks:

```
core/template
catalog/product_bestseller
```

And I've tried adding the bestseller.phtml to other templates, like my base folder. I also looked on stackexchange, but the "solutions" I found didn't work for me. What do I do to fix this?

Edit:
My system.log says the following: `Security problem: <span>catalog</span>/product_bestseller has not been whitelisted.`

But I did allow `catalog/product_bestseller` and `core/template` like I said above:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing the caches and re-indexing ?

Comment: Yes, I cleared my cache and re-indexed.

Comment: Default Magento do not have catalog/product_bestseller, is it that from a custom?

Comment: Yes I think it's custom. I didn't create the webshop, so I'm not sure how it was build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure allowed variables and blocks in `System > Permissions > Blocks` and `System > Permissions > Variables`.

you have to add `core/template` and `catalog/product_bestseller` block there.
This feature was added in Community Edition 1.9.2.2 and Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.2

**Update :**
Go to *permission_variable* table in the database and delete *core/template* and
*catalog/product_bestseller* entries as these are blocks not variables.

I think you are missing some files in your installation.Like bestseller block and layout updates.

Please refer following for more help by Amasty [How to display bestselling products in Magento + source code](https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-display-bestselling-products-in-magento-source-code/)

Comment: As I said, I already did this. I also tried creating allowed variables in `System > Permissions > Variables`, but this didn't help.

Comment: @user3478148 are you getting any errors in frontend or exception log or system.log files?

Comment: My system.log does say: `Security problem: <span>catalog</span>/product_bestseller has not been whitelisted.`, but `core/template` and `catalog/product_bestseller` are allowed in both blocks and variables.

Comment: @user3478148 can you update your question with the screenshots of the whitelisted block and variables and  systemlog

Comment: I've updated the question. :)

Comment: @user3478148 check the updated answer and if it works for you accept the answer

Comment: I've tried this, but this doesn't work. Also I only added it to the variables because you told me to do this in your answer.

Comment: @user3478148 I mentioned to move only blocks. Did you delete those from variables?

Comment: Yes I removed them. As I said, this didn't work.

Comment: @user3478148 have you cleared caches? Are you still getting same messaeg in the systemlog or exception log?

Comment: I cleared my cache, the whitelisted error is gone. I'm not receiving any other errors, but the block still isn't being displayed.

Comment: @user3478148 Then there may be some errors in your template for bestsellers.

Comment: When I empty the template and simply write text in it, it doesn't show either. It's like it's unable to find the template.

Comment: I was wrong. The whitelist error returned today..

Comment: @user3478148 Please check updated answer

Comment: That blog helped me fix it! Turns out I had to use a page instead of a static block, because it needed a layout. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Jumping from Magento 1.5.x to 1.9.x can be dangerous without upgrading your template.

You should check into `catalog/product/bestseller.phtml` and try to understand if it is using some obsoleted method.

To make a simple test just temporary remove `catalog/product/bestseller.phtml` so it will take from your `base/default` and see if it works.

P.S: Default Magento installation does not have any block called `catalog/product_bestseller`, is it coming from a custom? If yes you should check its compliance.

Comment: When I completely empty bestseller.phtml and just put text in the file, nothing is visible either. Also the bestseller.phtml is the same as the default one. I think theres nothing wrong with the bestseller.phtml, I think it's going wrong with calling the file.

The temporary remove doesn't work either.